# Oracle Apex& Rapid Application development

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to develop small-medium size web applications.
I wanna to use Oracle apex but I am not sure that whether apex is supporting other databases( MsSql, MySql,Sqlite)

web applications will have different properties.
Developing these web applications with ASP .NET can take long time. Because you should work on UI Design, you should write stabile and flexible data access layer.

As I know in Oracle Apex,designing is more faster and easier. There are some templates so deveopers who do not have strong design knowledge can design web pages. As I know by Oracle Apex, web pages can be prepared faster than .Net.

Are there any alternative tools for other databases rather than oracle?
And do you think that oracle apex is being stabile and have a good support in OTN or other platforms?

Thanks&Regards

Comment: To answer the question about whether apex is supprting other databases, I would not recommend it, since apex is built for Oracle. **If** you want to use it on other databases, it is ported for other databases, see [this](http://jes.blogs.shellprompt.net/2008/04/01/apex-ported-to-mysql-and-sqlserver/).

Comment: That Apex port link is a joke BTW!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Application Express (APEX) runs inside an Oracle database.  You can create database links from Oracle to a non-Oracle database using Heterogeneous Connectivity so that your APEX application can manipulate data stored in a non-Oracle database.  But you need to have the Oracle database in place in order for APEX to run.

APEX is certainly pretty stable-- Oracle has released a number of different versions (4.0 most recently).  And the underlying project has been around for a decade (it was previously HTML DB).  It's got a strong development team and a very strong developer community in and around OTN.  I've personally used it for a number of years and found it very productive.

There are, of course, other RAD development tools and frameworks that are not tied to the Oracle database.  Ruby on Rails and PHP with [one of the various PHP frameworks](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/11/02/24/221231/Drupal-Competes-As-a-Framework-Unofficially), for example, both have relatively strong developer communities and are not focused on Oracle.  Of course, you probably won't find the most vibrant communities for these products on OTN.

Comment: Thank you.Do you have any problems about User interface design in Oracle Apex? Does designing a web site is apex is easier than designing by visual studio .net or eclipse?

Comment: @innot - I'm not completely sure what you're asking.  No framework is going to eliminate all problems of user interface design just like no language that is going to eliminate all problems of application development.  Since I primarily do PL/SQL development these days, I find APEX far more productive than a JEE framework.  But that's a very personal thing-- plenty of developers would prefer something like ADF.